# how to fix header on scroll after using eventListener' scroll'

Tags: javascript, html, css

In my Html code, I want to make a header to be fixed-top when scrolled. It is working fine when I write javascript code within body tag.but when I'm creating a new .js file & writing .js file path in script tag then the page doesn't scroll down

```
enter code here
const nav = document.getElementById("main")
        let topOfNav = nav.offsetTop;
            function fixNav() {
                if (window.pageYOffset >= topOfNav) {

                   nav.classList.add('fixed-nav')
                } else {
                    nav.classList.remove('fixed-nav')

                }
            }
            window.addEventListener('scroll', fixNav)
     .fixed-nav {
      position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%; 
            }
 <nav class="navbar  navbar-expand-lg navbar-light" id="main">
                        <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">
                            <img class="top_logo" src="logo.jpg"                    
                             alt="">TestMyCode
                        </a>
 </nav>
 <script src="theme.js"></script>
```

I have written this  after jQuery,popper.js and bootstrap.min.js. Initially  in header I have added

```
enter code here
```

But page stops scrolling.It stucks at top position.how to make it scroll when js added through script tag?

Comment: Try adding the `<script src="script.js"></script>` just above the closing `<body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

Based on your html you wrote this:

```
<script src="theme.js"></script>
```

Try doing it like this...

```
   <html>
        <head>
           <script type = "text/javascript" src = "filename.js" ></script>
   </head>

        <body>
      .......
        </body>
   </html>
```

It is also important to note that if you have the file inside a folder you need to account for that in the src 
If it is not the file directories you will need to provide the absolute file path

Comment: Ok..I will try this.Js file is in the same folder where HTML file is present.

Comment: I tried this..placing script  inside <head>.but then if I print value of topOfNav in console it returns ..Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'offsetTop' of null.

Comment: and when i put script inside <body> then it returns topOfNav value 50 in console but then it stops scrolling.

Comment: It is working.. the problem was with theme.js file.In that file I was writing document.body.classList.add('fixed-nav').when I changed to nav.classList.add('fixed-nav') then it works...thank you